# Convert tiff to dicom using Matlab

Tags: matlab, tiff, dicom, imagej

I have a series of `dicom` images and did change the HUs in the images using `MATLAB` scripts, then I imported them in `ImageJ` for display. Then I realised I can modify the images using `ImageJ` gui (which much easier, just moving the mouse). However, when I saved the modified images in `ImageJ`, they were saved in `tiff` format. 
My question is that, is there a way to save images in imageJ as dicom format ?
or is there away to convert tiff format to dicom using `MATLAB` ?

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert tiff format to dicom with dicomwrite:

```
dicomwrite( imread('input_image.tif'), 'output_image.dcm')
```

Answer (score 2):

The following plugins allow writing DICOM files directly from ImageJ:

- [DICOM Import and Export plugins](http://www.iftm.de/telemedizin/dcmimex.htm)
- [The Tudor DICOM Tools](http://santec.tudor.lu/project/dicom)